# use windows vpn tunnel from linux vm image

Tags: linux, windows, vpn

I have a windows xp desktop with a linux centos vmware image running on it

Due to some issues I am having lately with vpnc on linux, I would like to know if I can route

vpn traffic from linux to windows.

So I will connect to the vpn from windows (with cisco's vpn client) and I would like to route

traffic, for a specific IP, on linux so that it uses windows's vpn tunnel

Is this posible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can route your Linux traffic through the Windows (host) VPN session if the Linux guest is setup with a NAT NIC through the hypervisor.

Comment: How can I verify this my friend? Thanks for the help

Comment: I changed the vm's nic settings from bridged to nat and added an entry on the vm's routing table, so that it sends traffic for the host I want to access on the other side of the vpn, through the IP of the windows host, but no luck

Comment: No need to change any routing tables on the VM once its virtual NIC is set for NAT.

Comment: Excellent mate. Thanks. Worked like a charm. Started the vpn tunnel on Windows, changed the vm's nic to NAT and restarted the network and voilla.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.